# Reference for complex curve theory

Tags: complex-geometry, projective-geometry, curves

Recently, I started to study complex curve theory with textbook written by Clemens. The thing is, I think I need a little more references for this study. I think my background is not enough. What I studied before is half of the elementary differential geometry of O'neil, most of the Dummit and Foote, number fields by Marcus. But this book starts with some projective geometrical concepts, and also there is NO exercise in this book. I'm trying to read some wikipedia articles to cover my background, but I'll appreciate if there is any other nice references to read with this book. Thank you.